# .NET form authentication along side with OpenIDConnect is it possible

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, single-sign-on

We have a legacy .NET WebForm Saas application that uses .NET Framework 4.7.2 and authentication logic via the legacy web form authentication against local SQL database.  It tracks the authenticated session via cookie which is the standard for form authentication.

We recently have a customer who requests SSO using their Azure AD to authenticate into our application.  Upon doing research around I've come up with SAML and OpenId Connect and I'm leaning toward OpenId Connect.

The challenge is while this customer uses Azure AD, another customer may use AWS AD or some still wants to use the standard login form on our login page.

Is this possible to have form authentication work along side with SSO? I'm still educating myself in SSO and it is confusing to say the least but I generally see people use an identity provider with multiple applications whereas we seems to go down the road of a single application using multiple identity providers while still support its own authentication method.

Comment: Yes, you just have multiple links on your login page that trigger oauth to multiple providers but you can even issue a forms cookie on successful SSO. And still issue the very same cookie on username/password auth

Comment: @WiktorZychla that is exactly what we are trying to do.  Do you know where we can find an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, that's doable. We have built a no-code/low-code solution for people to implement this. Here is a demo website. https://demo.datawiza.net/login

Click SSO at the bottom. Inputting company-a brings you an Okta login page; inputting company-b brings you to an azure ad login page.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out.  I feel like SSO is more of a top down approach which is you have one single identity provider provide SSO services to multiple applications such as within a company that uses Azure AD, they can federate it to multiple service providers ( application #1, application #2 and so on) .  Whereas I feel like what we are trying to accomplish is one service provider or application that interact with multiple identity providers because one customer may use Azure AD and another may use AWS DS ect...

Comment: @Fylix you are right. For internal apps, they usually only have one centralized IdP used by internal employees. For b2b customer-facing apps, they need to support multiple IdPs since the customer are using different IdPs as you mentioned.